# Missing solution in quadratic equation

Tags: geometry, vectors, quadratics

This is a reformulation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733865/sage-math-why-does-there-exist-a-solution-when-values-are-given-but-none-for-a) to better fit this forum. I removed the mentioning of sage math and this question is now 100% math.

Given, the following quadrilateral:

[image: quad]

I want to describe the position of point X in terms of a multiple $t$ of the vector $HG$. The points $H$ and $G$ themselves are described by multiples $s$ of the vectors $DC$ and $AB$, respectively.

We end up with the following equations:

$$
X = H + t(G-H) \\
H = s(C-D)+D \\
G = s(B-A)+A \\
$$

As an example, lets take the following quadrilateral:

$$
A=(1,2) \\
B=(3,2) \\
C=(2,0) \\
D=(0,0) \\
$$

We want to find $s$ and $t$ describing the point $X=(1.25,0.5)$ in the quadrilateral. Here a sketch of the geometric setup:

[image]

One can easily see that $X$ cuts $HG$ at $t=0.25$ and that $H$ and $G$ cut $DC$ and $AB$ at $s=0.5$, each.

This is also affirmed by inserting $s=0.5$ and $t=0.25$ into the formulas above. It will result in $H=(1,0)$ and $G=(2,2)$ and $X=(1.25,0.5)$ (the original point).

Now I want a formula which, given any point $X$ inside the quadrilateral gives me $s$ and $t$. To that end I rearrange the above three formulas and solve for $s$ and $t$. After plugging in $H$ and $G$ into $X$, there are two equations, one for the x-coordinates and one for the y-coordinates of the points. Since there are two missing variables $s$ and $t$ this should be solvable.

Since the derivation is super lengthy I started out with letting sage math solve it for me. I wrote about my experience and failure in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733865/sage-math-why-does-there-exist-a-solution-when-values-are-given-but-none-for-a) I already mentioned above. To rule out any problem with sage math I ended up doing it by hand. Here is the derivation for $s$:

$$
X = H + t(G-H) \\
H = s(C-D)+D \\
G = s(B-A)+A \\
s = \frac{X_x +t(D_x- A_x) - D_x}{C_x-D_x+t(B_x-A_x-C_x+D_x)} \\
t = \frac{X_y +s(D_y- C_y) - D_y}{A_y-D_y+s(B_y-A_y-C_y+D_y)} \\
$$

Plugging in $t$ into $s$ we arrive at a quadratic equation (my full derivation exists but is commented out for readability - it is the same solution sage math gives):

$$
0 = as^2 + bs + c \\
s_{1,2} = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
a = (D_x-C_x)(B_y-A_y-C_y+D_y)-(D_y-C_y)(B_x-A_x-C_x+Dx) \\
b = (D_y-A_y)(C_x-D_x)+(X_x-D_x)(B_y-A_y-C_y+D_y)-(X_y-D_y)(B_x-A_x-C_x+D_x)-(A_x-D_x)(D_y-C_y) \\
c = (A_y-D_y)(X_x-D_x)-(A_x-D_x)(X_y-D_y) \\
$$

As you can see, one ends up with a quadratic equation with parameters $a$, $b$ and $c$ given in the last lines. My derivations should be correct because as far as I can see they equal the result I got in sage math.

Now, when one plugs in the example values for $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ into $a$, then the result will be zero. This will result in a division by zero.

My question: clearly from a geometric point of view, there is a solution for $s$ and $t$ for the example values of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. Why is there none when solving the equation for $s$ and $t$?

And more practically: how can I determine $s$ and $t$ for any given $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $X$ without running into this problem?

If I can find the solution for this, then it would solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733583/im-looking-for-the-name-of-a-transform-that-does-the-following-example-images).

Here the values $a$, $b$ and $c$ that solve $0=at^2+bt+c$:

$$
a = (D_y-A_y)(B_x-A_x-C_x+D_x)-(D_x-A_x)(B_y-A_y-C_y+D_y) \\
b = (D_y-A_y)(C_x-D_x)+(X_y-D_y)(B_x-A_x-C_x+D_x)-(X_x-D_x)(B_y-A_y-C_y+D_y)-(C_y-D_y)(D_x-A_x) \\
c = (C_x-D_x)(X_y-D_y)-(C_y-D_y)(X_x-D_x) \\
$$

Unsurprisingly, the solution for $t$ works analogous to $s$.

Comment: Just a hint: if you want help from the community, try making it easy for us. Personally, I do not have the willpower to read the wall of text derivation you wrote, and I suspect 90% of other users feel the same way. I suggest you make a reader's digest of what you want to calculate.

Comment: damn. now I know how my friends feel in math class.

Comment: @5xum the derivation is not that important. As I wrote, sage math gives the same solution so I suspect the solution is correct.

Comment: OK, so the derivation is not important. Then don't write the whole thing. I am speaking for a very large part of the community when I say this: "I am not bothering with questions like this." A shorter question with a clearly defined problem will be much more constructive. This is my advice, of course, so do what you feel is best.

Comment: @5xum thanks, I commented out the derivation steps and left the important bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you get an equation $$as^2 + bs + c = 0$$ for $s$. I believe your derivation is correct (I have not checked it, so I am not sure). You say that the problem is that $a=0$. I see no problem with that:

If it is correct chat $a=0$, well then your equation is actually $bs+c=0$ and the solution is $s=-\frac{c}{b}$.

Comment: I think you are missing a minus but holy moly if that is true, that would solve my problem! Unfortunately I get a wrong value for s but that might just mean that I made an error somewhere. I'll come back after having tried more. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, I did miss a minus, I fixed it now. But still, the point remains that a quadratic equation where the leading coefficient is $0$ is just a simple linear equation.

Comment: It works!!! This is super amazing! Thanks a lot! I would not have managed without your help and it's a pity I can't give you more points as a reward :D Thank you! :)